# want to entry the same data twice to many rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to submit the informations to another sheet.
the problem is I can't entry the data in the save cell into another row

```
function submit(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();              
 var formS = sheet.getSheetByName('sheet1'); //data entry sheet
 var dataS = sheet.getSheetByName('sheet2'); //data sheet
  var values = [[formS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("B7").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("B8").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("B9").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("D6").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("D7").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("D8").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("D9").getValue(),
  formS.getRange("D10").getValue(),
 ]];
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9).setValues(values);
 clear1();
 {
 var Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS1 = Sheet1.getSheetByName('sheet1'); //data entry sheet
 var dataS1 = Sheet1.getSheetByName('sheet2'); //data sheet
  var values =
  [[formS1.getRange("B6").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("B7").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("B8").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("B9").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G6").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G7").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G8").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G9").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G10").getValue(),
 ]];
  dataS1.getRange(dataS1.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9).setValues(values);
 clear1();

 }}
```

Comment: How is the code not working? Are you getting errors? Nothing happening?

Comment: Also edit your question to include the function `clear1()`

Comment: It works but in second row it's only show the D6-D10.I mean in the first 4 cell the value is not entered.

Comment: The code from getting the data `D6:10` seems the same as the data to get `B7:9`. This points to another issue like having added the wrong column or file, which is impossible for us to tell without access to them. Could you double check that `sheet1!B7:9` is actually the range you want to get? Also, you could try using a formula for debugging purposes.

Comment: I tried change  B6:B9 in 
  [[formS1.getRange("B6").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("B7").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("B8").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("B9").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G6").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G7").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G8").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G9").getValue(),
  formS1.getRange("G10").getValue(),
To A6:A9 and the data was entered so it means the code is correct but when I use B6:B9 it's blank,in second row. Im the first row B6:B9,D6:D10 is 100% work.

Comment: What does `clear1()` do?